# Docker swarm scale

Tags: docker, scale, docker-swarm, worker

I have a cluster built with docker-swarm in which we run apache spark apps. In the cluster, I have a manager node and 3 worker nodes.In this cluster, we have a master container for spark and a lot of worker containers. I can scale the number of worker nodes by using following command.

```
sudo docker service scale spark_worker=<number of workers>
```

When I increase the number of worker, I want to create new containers on worker node not on manager node.

Comment: I solved the problem. After creating master and worker containers of spark, I change the availability of the manager node as pause. Then all new containers are distributed on other nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. `docker node update --availability=drain <nodename>` this will stop containers on the node and start them somewhere else, and prevent future containers from running on that node. Note that pause only prevents *new* containers on that node, and doesn't move existing ones.

   However, that method is quite limited. If you ever wanted to run *anything* on the manager like monitoring, logging, management GUI's, etc. you wouldn't be able to.
2. A more flexible method is to update the existing service to only run on worker nodes: `docker service update --constraint-add 'node.role==worker' <servicename>`. Then later if you wanted to run a service just on managers you could use `node.role==manager` on it.

Answer (score 0):

There is opportunity to specify replicas property inside deploy section.
So scale argument is not allowed. So one of  my services in  docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
xxx_nginx:
  image: nginx
  tty: true
  command: ["sh", "-c", "usermod -u 1000 nginx && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
  volumes:
    - "/home/pi/images:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro"
    - "/var/log/nginx:/var/log/nginx"
    - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
  deploy:
    replicas: 2
    placement:
      constraints:
        - "node.hostname==raspberrypi151"
```

So now I dont have to scale each time my service.